# PHP SOAP Request: Array with keys needed

Tags: php, arrays, soap, key

I have a Zend Soap Server and created an operation setUser(). This operation will eventually use the requested data and insert a new User object. Therefore I want to request an array with the values for the object.

Example:

```
$request = array("firstname" => "John", "lastname" => "Doe");
setUser($request) { ... }
```

The following request basically works for the array

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="...">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:setUser soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <setArray xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <item xsi:type="xsd:string">John</item>
            <item xsi:type="xsd:string">Doe</item>
         </setArray>
      </soap:setUser>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When dumping the array in my php code I get the numeric keys of the values only.

```
[0] => John
[1] => Doe
```

Is there a way to specify the key? I tried already:

```
<element name="firstname" xsi:type="xsd:string">John</element>
```

I want to achieve:

```
[firstname] => John
[lastname] => Doe
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the exact solution is with the Zend_SOAP_Server, but I think you want to be using a HashMap type, not an Array, which is much closer to what PHP means by "array" (I've come upon similar problems with NuSOAP: either array keys are discarded, or they're used as element names, both of which are invalid representations of PHP's "array" type)

You want to end up with a representation like this:

```xml
 <hash xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xsi:type="ns2:Map">
 <item>
  <key xsi:type="xsd:string">firstname</key> 
  <value xsi:type="xsd:string">John</value> 
 </item>
 <item>
  <key xsi:type="xsd:string">lastname</key> 
  <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Doe</value> 
 </item>
 </hash>
```

Most SOAP servers seem to decode this fine, even if their client implementation doesn't default to it.

Either that, or you need to define a custom document schema more like this:

```xml
 <userStruct xsi:type="myNamespace:userStruct">
 <firstname xsi:type="xsd:string">John</value></firstname>
 <lastname>Doe</lastname>
 </userStruct>
```

Personally, I tend to find SOAP creates more problems than it solves, but YMMV. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make `stdClass()`  from array for example like this:

```
function toObject($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
        if (is_array($value))
            $array[$key] = toObject($value);
    return (object)$array;
}
```

Then you can return that object and it will export to XML while handling server response like this:

```
  <firstname xsi:type="xsd:string">lastname</firstname> 
  <lastname xsi:type="xsd:string">Doe</lastname>
```

I'm using `Zend_Soap_Server()`.